# Quotient ring of a polynomial ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

> Given the ideal $I= \langle 3x^2 + y^2, xy \rangle \subset \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ show that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/ \langle  3x^2 + y^2, xy \rangle= \mathrm{span}_\mathbb{C}\{1,x,y,x^2 \}$.

I understand how to do a simpler problem, say if the ideal was $I= \langle x,y \rangle$ then it makes sense to me why $ \mathbb{C}[x,y]/ \langle x,y \rangle =\mathrm{span}_\mathbb{C} \{1 \}$ but when I try work through the problem with a more complicated ideal I cannot seem to make sense of it, particularly the $x^2$ confuses me. I’ve seen questions with similar examples on here but none explain the answer explicitly.

Comment: [No-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions) will not be received well here. Please consider improving your post.

Comment: @KReiser thanks for letting me know, appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Just to be clear, what you want to show is that $1,x,y,x^2$ is a basis for $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/ \langle  3x^2 + y^2, xy \rangle$ as a $\mathbb C$-vector space. Do not confuse this with the ideal $\langle 1, x, y, x^2 \rangle$. I normally write this as $\mathbb{C}\{1,x,y,x^2\}$ or $\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{C}} \{1,x,y,x^2\}$.

Comment: @TrevorGunn I think that’s correct, this example is from the examples section of this Wikipedia article: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milnor_number). Which I didn’t link because I didn’t think the example was specific to this article.

Answer (score 0):

$$\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(3x^2+y^2) = \Bbb{C}[x]+y\Bbb{C}[x]$$

$$\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(3x^2+y^2,xy^2)=\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(3x^2+y^2,x^3)=\Bbb{C}[x]/(x^3)+y\Bbb{C}[x]/(x^3)$$

$$\Bbb{C}[x,y]/(3x^2+y^2,xy^2)/(xy)=(\Bbb{C}[x]/(x^3)+y\Bbb{C}[x]/(x^3)) / (xy)= \Bbb{C}+x\Bbb{C}+x^2\Bbb{C}+y\Bbb{C}$$